# Windows 10 search does not find installed applications anymore

Tags: start-menu, windows-search, windows-10-v1703

I've recently installed Windows 10 on my PC (version 1703). Everything just works fine except for the search in the Start Menu. Search is able to find files, web and pre-installed apps but could not show me the desktop apps installed on the disk.

For example, to launch Word 2016, when I type Word in the search field, I see only WordPad or Windows store app but not the Word shortcut, whereas Office 2016 is installed.

I've already checked that the Windows Search service is running, and I've rebuilt the search index in the "Indexation options" in the "Control panel".

I don't know why it does not work, it is true that I've disabled all privacy settings I could see. Maybe it is the cause of the issue but I'm not sure. Do you have an idea?